# Getting Error converting data type varchar to float in log, but not in Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sharepoint, varchar

I am new to programming. I was tasked to find and fix the error stated in the title.  I have the below stored procedure where a form feeds a table. The SP passes parsing and execution in management studio, but when I run test inputs into the form, there is an error converting data type varchar to float in the log and the values input on the form does not end up in the db table. I cannot find where varchar is trying to convert to float.  Am I missing something?

```
Code:
/* GET ARGUMENTS PASSED FROM FORM */
@MYID AS NVARCHAR(4) = NULL,
@ZIP AS NVARCHAR(10) = NULL,
@NAME AS NVARCHAR(300) = NULL,
@EMAIL AS NVARCHAR(300) = NULL,
@NUMBER1 AS NVARCHAR(15) = NULL,
@NUMBER2 AS NVARCHAR(15) = NULL,
@OUT_MESSAGE AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
@SOURCE AS NVARCHAR(300) = NULL,
@REFR AS NVARCHAR(300) = NULL,
@SERVE AS NVARCHAR(300) = NULL,
@QT AS NVARCHAR(4) = NULL

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SET @MYID = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@ZIP,'|',','),'_',' '),';','-')
SET @ZIP = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@ZIP,'|',','),'_',' '),';','-')
SET @NAME = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@ZIP,'|',','),'_',' '),';','-')
SET @EMAIL = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@ZIP,'|',','),'_',' '),';','-')
SET @NUMBER1 = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@ZIP,'|',','),'_',' '),';','-')
SET @NUMBER2 = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@ZIP,'|',','),'_',' '),';','-')
SET @OUT_MESSAGE = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@ZIP,'|',','),'_',' '),';','-')
SET @SOURCE = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@ZIP,'|',','),'_',' '),';','-')
SET @REFR = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@ZIP,'|',','),'_',' '),';','-')
SET @SERVE = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@ZIP,'|',','),'_',' '),';','-')
SET @QT = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@ZIP,'|',','),'_',' '),';','-')


DECLARE @TODAY AS DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @WORK_ZIP AS NVARCHAR(10) = NULL
DECLARE @MESSAGE AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @INPOINT AS GEOGRAPHY = NULL

SET @MYID = (SELECT TOP 1 ISNULL(myid,'NONE') FROM VIEW_ZIPS WHERE EmailAddress IS NOT NULL AND myid LIKE(@MYID,4))
IF (@MYID IS NULL)
BEGIN
SET @MYID = 'NONE'
END

IF @MYID NOT LIKE 'NONE'
BEGIN
SET @SERVE = 'BRANCH1'
END

SET @OUT_MESSAGE = 'Something went wrong'
SET @OUT_MESSAGE = 'If problem continues, contact support'

DECLARE @CURR_REC AS INT

SET @CURR_REC = (SELECT TOP 1 ISNULL(REC_ID,0) FROM TBL_CONTACT WHERE (zip LIKE @ZIP AND name LIKE @NAME AND email LIKE @EMAIL AND number1 LIKE @NUMBER1 AND message LIKE @OUT_MESSAGE AND source LIKE @SOURCE AND refr LIKE @REFR AND serve LIKE @SERVE AND date LIKE @TODAY))
SET @CURR_REC = ISNULL(@CURR_REC,0)

IF (ISNULL(@NAME,'TEST') LIKE 'TEST' OR ISNULL(@NAME,'NONE') LIKE 'NONE'
BEGIN
SET @CURR_REC = 1
END

IF (ISNULL(@QT,'UNKNOWN') NOT LIKE 'UNKNOWN' AND @SOURCE NOT LIKE '%REFR')
BEGIN
SET @OUT_MESSAGE = (@OUT_MESSAGE + 'EST QT: ' +ISNULL(@QT,'UNKNOWN'))
END

IF (@CURR_REC < 1)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO TBL_CONTACT (zip, name, email, number1, number2, message, source, refr, serve, date, myid)
VALUES (@ZIP, @NAME, @EMAIL, @NUMBER1, @NUMBER2, @OUT_MESSAGE, @SOURCE, @REFR, @TODAY, @MYID)
END

SET @CURR_REC = (SELECT TOP 1 ISNULL(REC_ID,0) FROM TBL_CONTACT WHERE (zip LIKE @ZIP AND name LIKE @NAME AND @email LIKE @EMAIL AND number1 LIKE @NUMBER1 AD message LIKE @OUT_MESSAGE AND source LIKE @SOURCE AND refr LIKE @REFR AND serve LIKE @SERVE AND date LIKE @TODAY))
SET @CURR_REC = ISNULL(@CURR_REC,0)

IF @@NAME LIKE 'TEST' OR @NAME LIKE 'NONE')
BEGIN
SET @CURR_REC = 0
END

IF (@CURR_REC > 0)
BEGIN
SET @OUT_MESSAGE = 'Message body'
SET @OUT_MESSAGE = @OUT_MESSAGE + 'more body'

IF (@MYID NOT LIKE 'NONE') AND (@SERVE IN ('BRANCH1','BRANCH2'))
BEGIN
SET @OUT_MESSAGE = 'more code...'
END
```

Here is the log error:

08/07/2018 13:11:45.98  w3wp.exe (0x2778)                           0x12CC  SharePoint Foundation           Web Parts                       89a1    High        Error while executing web part: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Error converting data type varchar to float.     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteRead... 4fe25e3e-0d93-45e1-80ab-4d934b5af716

08/07/2018 13:11:45.98* w3wp.exe (0x2778)                           0x12CC  SharePoint Foundation           Web Parts                       89a1    High        ...erTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)     at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)     at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 start...  4fe25e3e-0d93-45e1-80ab-4d934b5af716

08/07/2018 13:11:45.98* w3wp.exe (0x2778)                           0x12CC  SharePoint Foundation           Web Parts                       89a1    High        ...Record, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)     at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)     at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments)     at System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigatorInternal()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigator()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.GetXPathNavigator(String viewP...  4fe25e3e-0d93-45e1-80ab-4d934b5af716

Comment: Could you please show us your error? The error should help to narrow down what the problem is.

Comment: @MichaelShopsin, post updated with error log information.